# Making sure at least 1 item in a TPopup menu is always selected

Tags: delphi, popup, radio-group

I have TPopup menu with 3 items setup with the following properties.

```
AutoCheck = True
RadioItem = True
```

and for the first menu item I set the `Checked` property to `True` as well so the menu has at least 1 item selected with it is initially displayed. This is all good and well, but if I click on the item that is currently selected, the check (dot) goes away and I want to make it so that at least 1 item in the popup is selected at all times. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The items in the group should also have the same non-zero [`GroupIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.GroupIndex). This, together with [`RadioItem`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.RadioItem) should make the items behave like a radio group.

However, it seems that [`AutoCheck`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Menus.TMenuItem.AutoCheck) doesn't respect `GroupIndex` and `RadioItem` properties, since it will clear the check when you click on a currently checked item.
(Arguably, this could be considered a bug in the VCL.)

Here's a workaround:

Set `AutoCheck` to `False`, assign all items the same non-zero `GroupIndex` and a common `OnClick` handler to check the clicked item like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ItemClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Sender as TMenuItem).Checked := True;
end;
```

Or use [Actions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Action_Lists), with them this seems to work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, After a bit of mucking around, I was able to make it work using both of the methods you posted. I would agree that this does seem like a bug in the VCL and a longstanding one at that because I am using Delphi7 and you are probably using something alot newer than that and the "bug" is still there in your version. Thanks again for the help tho, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the current version XE2 and it still behaves as described above.

Answer (score 0):

You can set following OnClick handler to all your radio group Menu Items:

```
procedure TForm1.MenuItemClickHandler(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        if Sender is TMenuItem then
        begin
            if not (Sender as TMenuItem).Checked then (Sender as TMenuItem).Checked:=True;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just went with using the actionlist method that @TOndrej suggested and it works fine now.